# Safe to connect a USB to Linux?

Tags: linux, usb-drive, ubuntu

A "friend" offerred me a USB with files.
I plugged it into my Ubuntu (version 12 or 14, don't remember) PC and an error appeared (don't remember exactly what was written..).
So I wasn't able to browse its content and I returned the USB stick to its owners..
Now I suspect that it contained malicious software.
How certain can I be in the security of Linux/Ubuntu OS from a USB originated threats?

Comment: too broad .. the only answer is that no system is invulnerable.

Comment: @AhmedJerbi You can say that on every question here on this site...

Comment: Especially when you don't have any details , so if you think that just using Linux can prevent you from an infected USB stick .. That's a big NO.

Comment: See also this really-useful Q&A: [Ask Ubuntu: How do I safely use a virus infected USB drive in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4508/327339)

Answer (score 2):

The only safe thing to do with unknown USB devices is not plug it in, but if you must then plug it into an air gapped freshly installed computer and wipe it again afterwards.

Comment: even if it's a windows' virus?

Comment: @Rami 1) you do not know it is a windows virus. It is an unknown. 2) You are also assuming that usb device is just a memory stick with a virus there are ways to emulate keyboards and mice and have it run a scripted set of keystrokes. This can be done in a cross platform way. 3) I have not covered that malicious code might infect firmware in various devices in which case one needs more than just a wipe to get rid of it (this is much rarer, but not impossible) hence why not plugging it in is the safest course of action.

Comment: Fundamentally, from a security perspective, USB is fundamentally insecure. We count it as physical access, but there is worse physical interfaces out there (expresscard, thunderbolt and firewire) where something called DMA (Direct Memory Access) exists where the device can directly modify data in main system memory bypassing the operating system entirely.

Comment: OK then please answer me this: Would the average person (with average knowledge in technology) could download an extremely sophisticated  malware? Is this kind of malware easily available to the "general public" ? ("is it downloadable easily?")

Comment: No, but that wouldn't be how I would get someone infected, an old penetration test trick is to throw a few memory sticks over the fence into some business' carpark and let the employees plug them in "to find a document that would allow them to be returned to the owner). Sometimes such things end up not working quite that way, Stuxnet for example was specifically targeted against a certain power facility in Iran using both USB memory sticks and network as infection vectors to end up on that specific network, However that didn't stop 40% of infections in other countries.

Answer (score 0):

No usb device is save. Specially [this](http://hackaday.com/2015/10/10/the-usb-killer-version-2-0/), where software will not protect you from having your computer damaged.

Answer (score 0):

### How to "safely" plug in a usb drive to Linux.

Here are my approaches:

1. **Option 1 (safest option I think): use a virtual machine**

   1. Install Ubuntu into a fresh virtual machine in [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (no cost to use), running in Ubuntu.

      1. ie: In Ubuntu, install Virtual Box, into which you install another Ubuntu system as a virtual machine.
   2. Plug in the USB drive and copy files to/from it as needed.
   3. Reset or delete the virtual machine when done.
   4. Note: if you need to share files between the virtual machine and your real, host computer, you can copy files to and from a shared folder that is shared between the virtual machine and your host computer.
2. **Option 2: boot from an Ubuntu live USB which is run from RAM**

   1. Install Ubuntu or similar to a live USB, intended to install Ubuntu.
   2. Boot from the live USB, but choose the option to "run from RAM" (assuming you have enough RAM).
   3. Once the OS boots and has copied everything needed from the thumb drive to RAM, unplug your boot drive.
   4. When done, just turning off the computer "wipes" the whole OS you just used, since it was all in RAM only.
   5. Note: if you need to get files to or from the thumb drive you are plugging in, you may be opening up a security vulnerability, which is why I feel like Option 1 above is better. You could, however:

      1. Mount your main drive.
      2. Plug in another USB drive.
      3. Leave the boot drive plugged in and use it to share files.
      4. I don't think any of these are super secure options, so do them only if you can't do Option 1 above.

### See also:

1. This really-useful Q&A: [Ask Ubuntu: How do I safely use a virus infected USB drive in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4508/327339)

   1. I posted a [slightly-more-thorough version of my answer above under this question too, here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1405614/327339).